# Get Images from supabase and display in react

Tags: reactjs, supabase

I am trying to retrieve the images and then display it on the page but somehow it is not displaying the images.
Instead, it throws this error:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (). Uncaught (in promise) StorageApiError: The resource was not found`

My images path is stored in the Projects table as a logo column and that same string is also stored in the bucket as well. I don't understand the issue

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState<Project[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getProjects()
  }, [])

  const getProjects = async () => {
    try {
      const {data: projects, error} = await supabase.from('Projects').select('*')
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      setProjects(projects as Project[])
    } catch (error) {}
  }

  const getSignedUrl = async (filename: string) => {
    const {data, error} = await supabase.storage.from('project-logo').createSignedUrl(filename, 60)
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    return data.signedUrl
  }

  return (
    <div className='row'>
      {projects.map((project) => (
        <div className='col-lg-4 mb-5' key={project.id}>
          <div className='card card-custom card-stretch-50 shadow'>
            <div className='card-header d-flex align-items-center'>
              <a href={`/project/${project.id}/detail`}>
                <h3 className='card-title'>{project.name}</h3>
              </a>
              <img src={`${getSignedUrl(project.logo)}`} alt={project.name} />
            </div>
            <div className='card-body'>{project.description}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Just like project, you also have to manage `signedUrl` with `useState`, and `getSignedUrl` in `useEffect`, don't run async function in `$` statement.

Comment: @Mee example? I have tried that but did not work.

Comment: You probably have the wrong path stored in your `logo` field.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1.Manage;

2.http request(the most fatal).
You have request data in map statement(loop request), that caused 400 error.

For 1:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState<Project[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getProjects()
  }, [])

  const getProjects = async () => {
    try {
      const {data: projects, error} = await supabase.from('Projects').select('*')
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      setProjects(projects as Project[])
    } catch (error) {}
  }

  return (
    <div className='row'>
      {projects.map((project) => (
        <div className='col-lg-4 mb-5' key={project.id}>
          <div className='card card-custom card-stretch-50 shadow'>
            <div className='card-header d-flex align-items-center'>
              <a href={`/project/${project.id}/detail`}>
                <h3 className='card-title'>{project.name}</h3>
              </a>
              <img src={`${project.logoUrl}`} alt={project.name} />
            </div>
            <div className='card-body'>{project.description}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

For 2.
Add logoUrl attr into project response on server side.

Comment: I have no server only react and supabase

Comment: That works same way in the end. In this case, you may need to improve your project database, add logoUrl field.

Comment: The field is already there